# my error is java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, swing, exception

I'm using jcreator. It says that process complete but when you go to switch then case 4 then choose numbers 1-9, it says that java.numberformatexception. What is causing this and how can I fix it? Im just a beginner here.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Exer29A {

    public static String inputdialog(String s)
    {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,s);
        return s;
    }   
    static void messagedialog(String r) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, r);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int xx, x1, x2;
        String n1, n2, LName, MName, FName;
        FName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What's your first name?");
        MName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What's your Middle name?");
        LName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What's your Last name?");
        n2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "So you are " + FName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + FName.substring(1).toLowerCase() + " " + MName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + MName.substring(1).toLowerCase() + " " + LName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + LName.substring(1).toLowerCase() + " " + "Do you wish to continue?[Y/N]");

        if (n2.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
            {
                 x1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What do you want to do? \n 1. Add 2 integers \n 2. Area of a rectangle \n 3. Area of a triangle \n 4. Know your fate.")); 
                    switch (x1)
                    {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        x1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter 1st integer."));
                        x2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter 2nd integer"));
                        messagedialog("The sum of two numbers is " + (x1+x2) );
                    }
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    {
                        x1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter 1st integer."));
                        x2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter 2nd integer"));
                        messagedialog("The area of the triangle is " + (x1*x2) );
                    }
                    break;
                    case 3:
                    {
                        x1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter base."));
                        x2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter height"));
                        messagedialog("The are of the triangle is " + ((double)(0.5*x1*x2)));
                    }
                    case 4:
                    {
                        xx = Integer.parseInt(inputdialog("Choose numbers 1-9"));
                    {

                            if (xx==1)
                                messagedialog("You will be successful!");
                            else if (xx==2)
                                messagedialog("You will have a beautiful life. Blessings would come to you.");
                            else if (xx==3)
                                messagedialog("You are handsome/gorgeous. But.....");
                            else if (xx==4)
                                messagedialog("You must study well.");
                            else if (xx==5)
                                messagedialog("Unfortunately, you are unfortunate.");
                            else if (xx==6)
                                messagedialog("You will be an environmentalist. You will be called the Keeper of the Forest.");
                            else if (xx==7)
                                messagedialog("You are nothing but luck. You will be poured out with luck.");
                            else if (xx==8)
                                messagedialog("8. Nothing but a number. Try again.");
                            else
                                messagedialog("Endowed with the gift to serve others, people with the lucky number 9 are able to freely create an easy and relaxed atmosphere. /n Your humanity is welcomed among their friends. Besides, they are brilliant, funny, smart and generous. ");    
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                    default:
                        messagedialog("invalid");
                    }
            }
        else if (n2.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
            System.exit(0);
        else
            messagedialog("INVALID");

    }

}
```

Exception stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Choose numbers 1-9" 
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Exer29A.main(Exer29A.java:50)
```

Comment: And where does the `NumberFormatException` occur?

Comment: There's no break between #3 and #4, not sure if that's deliberate.  What's your input for this condition?

Comment: Your error is `java.lang.NumberFormatException` actually. Error messages and exceptions and indeed all program output must be reported accurately. You should have included the entire stack trace in your question, not just some mangled version of the error message uncorrelated to the source code.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Choose numbers 1-9"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at Exer29A.main(Exer29A.java:50)

Comment: it will ask your name then choose what do you want to do then if you choose "4" to know your fate then "Choose numbers 1-9" and then that message will pop. it wouldnt output my if else statement inside

Comment: I repeat. You should have included the entire stack trace in your question. You can see for yourself that it's completely illegible in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike all of the other calls, for case '4', you call `inputDialog(...)` instead of `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter base.")`.  That's not the main problem.

The main problem is *what* `inputDialog(...)` returns.  It is not the same thing as what `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter base.")` returns.

Comment: `inputdialog` calls `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,s);` and returns a `String` like all the others...

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's true, but _which_ string does it return? (And don't answer the question, please).

Comment: I'll try to change it wait.

Comment: Wow. Case solved. Thanks guys. Im really have a hard time in user defined methods. It's a requirement for us to use it. Anyways. God bless. :)

Comment: @pcolor Basically, as you go forward in programming; everything will be in a method.  So it's ok to make mistakes now, as long as you learn from these mistakes, you are saving yourself a lot of pain in the months and years ahead.

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's fun when the bug is so simple, and yet subtle.